# Installing php extensions does not work

Tags: apache2, php

When i tried to excec composer install, showns an error sayin that some extensions are needed. Then i uncomment the extensions on the php.ini, install those extensions via "sudo apt-get install curl" and restart the apache server, but still not work, do not know what else to do.

```
armando@armando-VIT-P2400:/var/www/html/zxccxz$ sudo composer install
[sudo] contraseña para armando: 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried:     /usr/lib/php/20170718/curl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/curl: cannot open shared      object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so  (/usr/lib/php/20170718/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file   or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl: cannot  open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718  /openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file:  No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root   for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested PHP extension ext-pdo_sqlite * is missing from your  system. Install or enable PHP's pdo_sqlite extension.
Problem 2
- Installation request for league/uri-components 1.8.2 -> satisfiable by  league/uri-components[1.8.2].
- league/uri-components 1.8.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP  extension curl is missing from your system.
Problem 3
- Installation request for paypal/rest-api-sdk-php 1.14.0 -> satisfiable  by paypal/rest-api-sdk-php[1.14.0].
- paypal/rest-api-sdk-php 1.14.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP  extension curl is missing from your system.
Problem 4
- Installation request for stripe/stripe-php v4.13.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v4.13.0].
- stripe/stripe-php v4.13.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
Problem 5
- Installation request for symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.1 -> satisfiable  by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.2.1].
- symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
Problem 6
- Installation request for symfony/security-bundle v4.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v4.2.1].
- symfony/security-bundle v4.2.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
```

Comment: Are you supposed to uncomment lines in php.ini? Please re-comment those lines and then restart Apache!

Comment: uncomment extension lines in php.ini means that those extensions are enable.

Comment: I know, but in Ubuntu, never had to use it! Just install from terminal and I think that took care of every thing! Used that in Windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Use:

```
sudo apt-get install php-**extenation name here**
```

Then you must restart Apache Service, Use:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```